# Is every equivalence of monoidal categories a monoidal equivalence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $C$ and $D$ be monoidal categories. Let $T:C \to D$ be a functor that gives the equivalence of $C$ and $D$ as just categories.

My question is whether such an equivalence $T$ is always a monoidal equivalence or not.

If this is true, could you give me a proof?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certainly not, for roughly the same reason that if $X,Y$ are monoids, then a bijection between the underlying sets need not respect the monoid operations. If you understand this claim, you can answer your question too.

Comment: To be more explicit, any example of a bijection between monoids which is not a monoid homomorphism is also and example of an equivalence between discrete monoidal categories which is not monoidal.