# When an equivalence is a monoidal equivalence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories

I want to understand the followings from "*Tensor Categories*" by Etingof, Gelaki, Nikshych, and Ostrik.

> **Remark 1.5.3** It is easy to show that if $F: C \to C'$ is an equivalence of monoidal categories, then there exists a monoidal equivalence $F^{-1}: C' \to C$ such that the functors $F \circ F^{-1}$ and $F^{-1} \circ F$ are isomorphic to the identity functor as monoidal functors.

As indicated in the answer to the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1501161), not every equivalence is a monoidal equivalence.

So what I am missing? Does Remark 1.5.3 contain more information than just a equivalence so that I can prove it is a monoidal equivalence? Or I am confused by some definitions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of "equivalence" is context-sensitive, just as for "isomorphism". Here, it is clear that "equivalence of monoidal categories" means the same as "monoidal equivalence".

Comment: In that case, what is "easy to show" in Remark 1.5.3? It seems that it is a definition of "monoidal equivalence".

Comment: There is more than one possible definition. For instance, one might define monoidal equivalence to be "strong monoidal functor that is fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects".

Comment: @ZhenLin *bump* Is that definition of a monoidal equivalence distinct to the one (Definition 12) given in math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-winter2001/definitions.pdf ?

Answer (score 2):

The authors define: "A monoidal functor F is said to be an equivalence of monoidal categories if it is an equivalence of ordinary categories." I.e. a monoidal equivalence F is an equivalence, and F is equipped with a monoidal structure J. Since F is an equivalence, it admits a quasi-inverse G such that FG and GF are isomorphic to the respective identity functors.

What is less obvious (to a beginner like myself) is that G also may equipped with its own monoidal structure.